# How can I make hls.js send the cookie in request header upon requesting encryption key

Tags: javascript, cookies, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I tried

```
var config = {
       xhrSetup: function (xhr) {
          xhr.withCredentials = true; // do send cookies
       }
    };
```

but this doesn't work. 
The Cookie is sent on playlist request and on segment request no matter if I enable credentials in the xhrSetup or not... but not on key request.
For securing the content I need to identify the user before handing out the key.
It's possible to set an "X-Cookie" as i wrote in the answer, but how would I send the session cookie?

Answer (score 3):

I set an "X-Cookie" like this:

```
    var config = {
        debug: true,
        xhrSetup: function (xhr,url) {
            xhr.withCredentials = true; // do send cookie
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Cookie", read_cookie('SESSIONID'));
        }
    };
```

on the other side it needs

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Cookie"
```

the read_cookie function:

```
function read_cookie(key) {
   var result;
   (result = new RegExp('(?:^|; )' + encodeURIComponent(key) + '=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie)) ? (result[1]) : null;
   console.log('result : ' + result[1]);
   return result[1]
}
```

is there a way to send a Cookie value though?

Comment: in the "read_cookie(key)" function just return this:

return key + '=' + result[1]